# Matlab/Octave: can't plot equation

Tags: plot, octave

I'm using Octave to plot a simple equation, but it returns an empty plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ITNq.png)
 here is the code:

```
# Computing of Zin
# Constants
RL=50;
L=1;
mu=4e-7*pi;
eps=1;
nu=3e8/sqrt(eps);
s=50;
r=7.5;
l=(mu/pi)*log((s-r)^2/r^2);
c=1/(l*nu^2);
R0=sqrt(l/c);
beta=2*pi*sqrt(l*c);

# Equation
Zin=R0*(RL+R0*tan(beta*f)*1i)/(R0+RL*tan(beta*f)*1i);
printf("l=%e ; c=%e ; R0=%f ; beta=%e\n",l,c,R0,beta);
printf("Zin(f) = %f for f = %d Hz.\n",Zin,f);

# Plot Zin(f)
f=logspace(7,11);
figure(1);
semilogx(f,Zin);
title('Zin(f)');
```

Octave returns this:

```
l=1.387681e-006 ; c=8.006964e-012 ; R0=416.304253 ; beta=2.094395e-008
Zin(f) = 444.026370 for f = 10000000 Hz.
Zin(f) = 12067926.406393 for f = 14563484 Hz.
Zin(f) = 17575106.248548 for f = 21209508 Hz.
Zin(f) = 25595479.226995 for f = 30888435 Hz.
Zin(f) = 37275937.203149 for f = 44984326 Hz.
Zin(f) = 54286754.393239 for f = 65512855 Hz.
Zin(f) = 79060432.109077 for f = 95409547 Hz.
Zin(f) = 115139539.932645 for f = 138949549 Hz.
Zin(f) = 167683293.681101 for f = 202358964 Hz.
Zin(f) = 244205309.454865 for f = 294705170 Hz.
Zin(f) = 355648030.622312 for f = 429193426 Hz.
Zin(f) = 517947467.923120 for f = 625055192 Hz.
Zin(f) = 754312006.335461 for f = 910298177 Hz.
Zin(f) = 1098541141.987557 for f = 1325711365 Hz.
Zin(f) = 1599858719.606057 for f = 1930697728 Hz.
Zin(f) = 2329951810.515372 for f = 2811768698 Hz.
Zin(f) = 3393221771.895329 for f = 4094915062 Hz.
Zin(f) = 4941713361.323838 for f = 5963623317 Hz.
Zin(f) = 7196856730.011529 for f = 8685113738 Hz.
Zin(f) = 10481131341.546831 for f = 12648552169 Hz.
Zin(f) = 15264179671.752302 for f = 18420699693 Hz.
Zin(f) = 22229964825.261909 for f = 26826957953 Hz.
Zin(f) = 32374575428.176399 for f = 39069399371 Hz.
Zin(f) = 47148663634.573898 for f = 56898660290 Hz.
Zin(f) = 68664884500.429985 for f = 82864277285 Hz.
Zin(f) = 100000000000.000000 for f =
```

I don't understand the problem. I also tried to make it a function to plot it with fplot but was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is f declared before this line 

Zin=R0*(RL+R0*tan(beta*f)*1i)/(R0+RL*tan(beta*f)*1i);

?

Comment: Actually it's as it is, declared after the equation. I didn't realize. But it doesn't change anything if I put it before the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the code

> semilogx(f,Zin);

to

> semilogx(f,Zin, '*');

Then check the output, where points are shown as '*'.

Update:

Here is the code:

```
function zin
    RL=50;
    L=1;
    mu=4e-7*pi;
    eps=1;
    nu=3e8/sqrt(eps);
    s=50;
    r=7.5;
    l=(mu/pi)*log((s-r)^2/r^2);
    c=1/(l*nu^2);
    R0=sqrt(l/c);
    beta=2*pi*sqrt(l*c);
    f=logspace(7,11);

    # Equation
    printf("l=%e ; c=%e ; R0=%f ; beta=%e\n",l,c,R0,beta);

    Zin = R0*(RL+R0*tan(beta*f)*1i)./(R0+RL*tan(beta*f)*1i);

    # Plot Zin(f)


    size(Zin)


    semilogx(f,Zin,'r-x');

    title('Zin(f)');

end
```

The image is shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6yZ9.png).

Comment: I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/LllGj.png).  

The value seem to correspond to the second line of what Octave returns:  

    Zin(f) = 444.026370 for f = 10000000 Hz.
  
But all the next values returned by Octave are wrong. And I don't understand why it gives a constant line on the plot.

Comment: Thank you.
Could you explain me briefly why it didn't work and how you fixed it please?

Comment: @user1787461 in your code, f is a vector of size (1 x n), whereas Zin is only a variable i.e. a vector of size 1 x 1 (this means, same value for every frequency, that's why a line parallel to x-axis showed up in the plot). So, you need to make Zin a vector of size 1 x n by calculating Zin over a loop of frequencies. Then, you can connect different points on plot through 'r-x' in semilogx. Now that you are satisfied with this answer, do two things: vote up this answer and mark this as accepted answer. ;) In case of doubts, don't hesitate to raise your doubts.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!
And just to be sure, this is the right way to plot? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @user1787461 please check the updated answer for a simpler way: You just need put a dot in the equation for Zin in your original code. "./" means divide the numerator by denominator element by element since numerator and denominator gives a vector of size (1 x n). Since you needed to show the plot, printing Zin with f is not needed. If you still need to print them, you need to loop over Zin and f values, as per the experience till now.